# malloc doesn't work for second element of list

Tags: c, linked-list, heap-memory

The function should create a linked list of structs, I've seen in the debugger that it allocates the memory for the first element, but the program crashes during the allocation of memory for the second element.

```
struct Tipologia{
    int mq;
    int prezzo;
    int n;
    char descrizione[100];
};

struct Nodo{
    struct Tipologia t;
    struct Nodo *next;
};

typedef struct Nodo* NODO;

struct Tipologia creaTipologia(){
    struct Tipologia t;
    printf("MQ?\n");
    scanf("%d", &(t.mq));
    printf("PREZZO?\n");
    scanf("%d", &(t.prezzo));
    printf("DISPONIBILI?\n");
    scanf("%d", &(t.n));
    printf("DESCRIZIONE?\n");
    int c;
    while ( (c = getc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n');
    fgets((t.descrizione), 100, stdin);
    return t;
}

NODO costruisciPalazzo(){
    int continua;
    NODO h= NULL;
    printf("VUOI COSTRUIRE UN APPARTAMENTO? 1 SI, 0 NO\n");
    scanf("%d", &continua);
    if(continua){
        NODO n= malloc(sizeof(NODO));
        h= n;
        n->t= creaTipologia();
        n->next= NULL;
        printf("VUOI COSTRUIRE UN APPARTAMENTO? 1 SI, 0 NO\n");
        scanf("%d", &continua);
        while(continua){
            NODO nodo= malloc(sizeof(NODO));
            n->next= nodo;
            n= nodo;
            n->t= creaTipologia();
            printf("VUOI COSTRUIRE UN APPARTAMENTO? 1 SI, 0 NO\n");
            scanf("%d", &continua);
        }
        n->next= NULL;
    }
    return h;
}
```

I've been following the instructions of my professor but it keeps on crashing without giving any error to explain what actually happens. It seems to work for my classmates and we can't figure out what the problem is. Please help

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(NODO))` allocates spaces for a *pointer*, not for the complete `struct Nodo` - so you end up invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: so should I do malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo)) instead?

Comment: Yes. Also this is one of the reasons many programmers frown upon hiding pointers behind `typedef`s (such as `typedef struct Nodo* NODO;`), it makes such errors harder to spot

Comment: You can do `sizeof(*NODO)`. You already have a `NODO` since `n` is a `NODO`. You need space for the thing it points to.

Comment: @UnholySheep ok, I checked and you were right, by doing malloc(sizeof(structNodo)) it's working

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `typedef` that hides the fact that `NODO` is a pointer. This is bad, as it creates confusing situations where you are expecting a type to have a certain size and be used with a certain syntax, but in effect it's something entirely different.

For instance, you have to do this:

```
h= n;
n->t= creaTipologia();
n->next= NULL;
```

It's confusing that both `h` and `n` are not explicitly declared as pointers, but you have to use the arrow notation.

My suggestion is that you either remove completely the `typedef` and use `struct nodo` in your code, or at least remove the pointer from the `typedef`. Do the same with the other structure for consistency:

```
typedef struct {
  int mq;
  int prezzo;
  int n;
  char descrizione[100];
} TIPOLOGIA;

typedef struct Nodo {
  TIPOLOGIA t;
  struct Nodo *next;
} NODO;
```

You can also simplify your `malloc` using the object as a reference for its size. For instance:

```
NODO *h = malloc(sizeof *h);
```

This avoids the need of specifying the type of `h` when calling `malloc`. It's better for reuse too.

Comment: Here is a good cite to use: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). Good use of the dereferenced pointer itself for the type-size in `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved simply by doing malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo)) instead of malloc(sizeof(NODO)), since with NODO it would allocate only the pointer, while with struct Nodo it allocates the whole element